# R fractional area calculations using the exactextractr package

Tags: raster, r, polygon, vector-grid

I have a question related to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368386/r-zonal-statistics-for-classes) question. I have a gridded shapefile, which has 256 grid polygons. This shapefile represents an area of interest, and that area of interest also has a raster. I want to know fraction area of the each of the polygons covered by the raster pixels. I have two classes in the raster o and 1. So based on the number of cells that have a value one, the function will return a value telling me that, for example, 60% of grid polygon 1 are covered with raster pixels that have a value one and 40% of grid polygon 1 are covered by raster pixels that have value 0. For such a task, can I use the exactextractr package in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are just 0 or 1, mathematically, the mean of the values within each polygon are the same as the proportion of 1's. Here is what you can do:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

r <- raster("./layers/r.tif")
g <- read_sf("./layers/grid.gpkg")

# mean values by polygon
ex <- extract(r, g, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)

# transform data into percent
results <- ex %>% mutate(Percent_0 = (1-r)*100) %>% mutate(Percent_1 = r*100)

head(results)
 ID         r Percent_0 Percent_1
1  1 0.9774000   2.26000  97.74000
2  2 0.8338000  16.62000  83.38000
3  3 0.8945000  10.55000  89.45000
```

[Here you can download the simple data to do so](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XWpO2fU1F4qJoLbbbgEJt069IsAgFUYS?usp=sharing).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This assumes perfect overlap (ie, the cells nest perfectly within each polygon). If only small slivers of cells intersected the polygon boundaries this could equate to a notable bias. The `exact_extract` function returns the cell value along with the fraction of the cell that intersects the polygon.